# Logging serial data to a new file for every day

Tags: putty, logging

I want to log the data received via the serial port to file on a daily base. Means for every day a new file should be created. I run a 24/7 test, where the device outputs it's state to the serial port. On the Windows PC I want to receive the data and log it to file. One file per day.

Currently I run a putty session for logging. Putty currently just creates a new file when the session is started. The file are getting really big so it can't really be handled, also the overview in a file with some million lines get lost.

Is there a way to log via putty and let putty create for every day a new log file? Or do you have any other ideas to handle this problem?

Comment: Must you use putty, or can it be something else as well?

Comment: Couldn't you just have a script that kills putty, renames the log file and then restarts putty at midnight every day?

Comment: can be something else as well, but I want to have one program or even better one service running to log

Answer (score 0):

[PuTTY *Log file name* box](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-logfilename) accepts special patterns that you can use to insert a date to the log file name:

> - `&Y` will be replaced by the current year, as four digits.
> - `&M` will be replaced by the current month, as two digits.
> - `&D` will be replaced by the current day of the month, as two digits.
> - `&T` will be replaced by the current time, as six digits (HHMMSS) with no punctuation.

---

*Though I'm not sure if PuTTY is the right tool for your task. Shouldn't you rather use [Plink](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter7.html)?*